# Can I transform percentage data using just the square root?

Tags: logistic, anova, data-transformation, percentage, transform

I have a data set with the number of larvae (out of 100) that have metamorphosed after 0,1,2, and 5 days. I want to perform a repetitive ANOVA on the results but they are not normally distributed. I've tried arcsine-square-root and logit but both don't produce a normal distribution. Can I just transform the data using the square root? Or is there a better way to deal with it?

Any help would be great!

Comment: It sounds like you have a binomial response variable and should use an appropriate GLM (probably logistic regression for starters) rather than shoehorn your data into an ANOVA.

Comment: Hi @Dave - I've tried using a binomial GLM but I get the following warning: 

In eval(family$initialize) : non-integer #successes in a binomial glm!

Is it therefore appropriate to use a quasi-binomial distribution?

Comment: Do you have non-integer values in your response variable ($y$)?

Comment: Yes as its percentage data so the y variable looks like this:
Met = 0
0
0
0
0.18
0.1
0.35
0.3
0.2
0.12
0.35
0.33
0.82
0.27
1
1

Comment: And then @Dave I have three variables: Temperature (14 or 18), pH (7.7 or 8.1), and Day (0,1,2, or 5)

Comment: Look at your error. It doesn’t like the non-integer $y$-values. Binomial distributions have integer values. Do you have the integer values of the number of larvae that hatched and number that didn’t? From your original post, it sounds like you can multiply by $100$ and be off and running.

Comment: So if I multiply by 100 I get this error: 
Error in eval(family$initialize) : y values must be 0 <= y <= 1

Comment: @Dave, this is the code I am inputting into R: model1 <- glm(Met ~ Day + pH, binomial, data = C1)

Comment: Your $y$ variable has to have a column with the number of successes (hatched) and another column with the number of failures (unhitched). Look around in the documentation for “family” of the glm function. // This basic logistic regression might not be a great model, but it’s a starting point.